# Showing an overview of the weekly hour registrations in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

Fellow coders,

I am having trouble with a project I have to realise for my internship company. I have an hourregistration system in which colleagues can fill in their worked hours in relation to the project - task. What I have to do now is to collect the weekly data that has been filled in using the data type `date` I filled in in the database. Using a dropdown at the top of my page to cycle through various weeks to gain the data of the user that is logged in..

My question is, how am I able to collect the weekly data using a dropdown at the top of my table so my boss can have an overview of the registration filled in by the currently logged in colleague.

I am literally stuck in this part of my project and I would love to receive some help...

It should look something like this

[image]

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service.  Show your code and we'll fix an isolated issue.

Comment: Oh I know it isnt, but then again. I have 0 clue where to start